# Vaadin plugin on Netbeans -- project depenencies & addons

Tags: netbeans, dependencies, vaadin

I'm getting the following error when i attempt to add https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/vaadin-charts to my Vaadin project:

> > java.lang.NullPointerException

```
at org.openide.filesystems.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:559)
at org.vaadin.netbeans.maven.directory.KnownLicense.getText(KnownLicense.java:51)
at org.vaadin.netbeans.maven.directory.AbstractLicenseChooser.acceptLicense(AbstractLicenseChooser.java:75)
at org.vaadin.netbeans.maven.directory.AbstractLicenseChooser.getLicense(AbstractLicenseChooser.java:47)
at org.vaadin.netbeans.maven.project.VaadinAction$AddonHandler.getLicense(VaadinAction.java:503)
at org.vaadin.netbeans.maven.project.VaadinAction$1.actionPerformed(VaadinAction.java:214)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6527)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6292)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4883)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:159)
```

> > [catch] at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
> >         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
> >         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
> >         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
> >         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
> >         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

I'm on Netbeans 8. These are my very first Vaadin efforts. i followed the steps showed on the video at https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/what-is-so-great-about-vaadin-netbeans-plugin.  haven't tempered with the project dependencies. however, "feels" like a dependency issue.

TIA.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error it looks like that the license for an add-on is missing. Can't say from the error stacktrace for sure, but looks like missing cval-3 license text [that has been just added](http://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/13098).

Not much you can do about that, but wait for a plugin update. Or maybe try with an another add-on with different license.

Answer (score 0):

Version 1.1.3 of the Vaadin NetBeans plug-in was released today and fixes this issue. You should update to that.